# godot 4 GameManager.gd:47 @ _on_area_2d_body_shape_entered(): This function can't be used during the in/out signal

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

hello ive been working on this godot project but get an error when trying to switch scenes the first time i switch from level 1 to 2 i get the error message stated in the title but it changes succesfully but when i try to change from level 2 to 3 it doesnt work

heres the code

```
extends Node

@onready var shuriken_count = %shuriken_count
var shurikens = 0
const Maxhealth = 100

var health = Maxhealth
 

@onready var health_bar = $"../UI/TextureProgressBar"

@onready var level_1 = $".."


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    health_bar.max_value = Maxhealth
    sethealthbar()
    
func sethealthbar():
    health_bar.value = health

func damage():
    health -= 20
    if health < 0:
        resetlevel()
    sethealthbar()
    
func resetlevel():
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()




func increaseshurikens():
    shurikens += 1
    shuriken_count.text = "shurikens: " + str(shurikens)
    
func decreaseshurikens():
    shurikens -= 1
    shuriken_count.text = "shurikens: " + str(shurikens)


func _on_area_2d_body_shape_entered(_body_rid, body, _body_shape_index, _local_shape_index):
    if (body.name == "CharacterBody2D"):
        Levels.level +=1
        get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://scenes/level_"+ str(Levels.level) +".tscn")
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states functions that remove nodes from the tree should not be called in signals.

Instead use [call_deffered](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-call-deferred) so the code is executed at the end of the frame:

```
func _on_area_2d_body_shape_entered(_body_rid, body, _body_shape_index, _local_shape_index):
    if (body.name == "CharacterBody2D"):
        call_deffered("change_level")

func change_level():
    Levels.level +=1
    get_tree().change_scene_to_file("res://scenes/level_"+ str(Levels.level) +".tscn")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have implemented the solution but i am still facing  errors E 0:00:12:0798   level_2.tscn::GDScript_s137n:44 @ _physics_process(): Parameter "body->get_space()" is null.
  <C++ Source>   servers/physics_2d/godot_physics_server_2d.cpp:997 @ body_test_motion()
  <Stack Trace>  level_2.tscn::GDScript_s137n:44 @ _physics_process()
E 0:00:08:0822   GameManager.gd:33 @ nextlevel(): This function can't be used during the in/out signal.

Comment: now the errors disappeared but it still doesnt work

Comment: Check the return value of change_scene_to_file. Mayber there is something wrong with loading your third level (assuming the part that does not work is still only the change from level 2 to 3). Also: Does your level 2 scene reset, or does nothing happen on 2 to 3?

Answer (score 1):

The following is my reasoning about the errors:

- The error in question happens because the `Area2D` is in use while changing from one space to another. Which, I believe is because the `Area2D` is in an autoload while you change the scene.

  Yes, using `call_deffered` as pointed in [Bugfish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77752235/402022) would address that.
- The error you posted in comments suggest you are trying to access some physics body while the transition is not done, which I presume that is in another autoload.

  In particular the error says "body->get_space()" is null, you can check that:

  ```
  func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
      if not PhysicsServer2D.body_get_space(get_rid()).is_valid():
          return

      # rest of the code
  ```

  The code above is written for a script attached to a physics object. If the problematic script is not a physics object, but uses one, you would want to use `get_rid()` on a reference to the physics object (e.g. `my_physics_object.get_rid()`) instead of just `get_rid()` in the code above.

However, that seems to be patching the issue, instead of getting a proper solution. So I can't guarantee another error won't pop up from some other part of your code.

So based on [Bugfish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77752235/402022), and assuming the code in question is an autoload, you could do this:

```
var changing_scene:bool = false


func _on_area_2d_body_shape_entered(_body_rid, body, _body_shape_index, _local_shape_index):
    if (body.name == "CharacterBody2D"):
        changing_scene = true
        call_deffered("change_level")

func change_level():
    Levels.level +=1
    var scene_path := "res://scenes/level_"+ str(Levels.level) +".tscn"
    var err := get_tree().change_scene_to_file(scene_path)
    if err == OK:
        changing_scene = false
    else:
        print("Error " + str(err) + " changing scene to " + scene_path)
```

Then the other autoloads can check `changing_scene` and if it is true, stop whatever they are doing until it is false again. *If the code in question is not an autoload, you might want to move `changing_scene` to an autoload for ease of access from other parts of the code.*

*Also, I added a `print` that will tell you if there was an error loading the new scene. If there was, check if the scene file exists and can be loaded correctly in the editor.*